# Ограничение пакетов на порт iptables

Tags: iptables

Открыт порт, как выставить ограничения на количество пакетов которые может отправить юзер на этот порт? Например 10 в секунду?

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3724 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3724 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 10/sec --hashlimit-mode  srcip,dstip --hashlimit-name Packets --hashlimit-htable-expire 60000 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
```

но что то не работает, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Я могу и ошибаться, но то, что вы описываете, похоже на трафик-шейпинг (traffic shaping) - ограничение пропускной способности канала, и решается средствами не только iptables (например, еще и tc -Traffic Control)

Comment: Посмготрите также тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/119611/